# How does STR-Transform works?

Tags: language-agnostic, x509, ws-security, xml-signature

How does the STR-Transform transformation algorithm works for XML Signature, when working with WS Security? I need to sign the SecurityTokenReference used for the signature on a SOAP message, and this is the required transformation for the security token. I am using an x509 certificate to do the signature, so the security token is this certificate. However, in the message I only need the reference to the certificate thumbprint.

Here is the signature structure that I need to replicate, and the only bit that I am missing is the signature reference to the SecurityTokenReference:

```
<dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <dsig:SignedInfo>
    <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <dsig:Reference URI="#Timestamp_C1Ih1AB1vpPT5uG2">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <dsig:DigestValue>fVSyToUO8yS131cV8oT1h6fa69Jvtt+pKFeP4BFf1P4=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </dsig:Reference>
    <!-- Other signature references -->
    <dsig:Reference URI="#str_U1sjQ5j8JtKnObLk">
      <dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#STR-Transform">
          <wsse:TransformationParameters>
            <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          </wsse:TransformationParameters>
        </dsig:Transform>
      </dsig:Transforms>
      <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <dsig:DigestValue>gRa3zakGn13XISoKpekB3zl0iDqb/LmNy7+aMDtzKIY=</dsig:DigestValue>
    </dsig:Reference>
  </dsig:SignedInfo>
  <dsig:SignatureValue>ptO...E9Q==</dsig:SignatureValue>
  <dsig:KeyInfo>
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                    xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"
                    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                    wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"
                    wsu:Id="str_U1sjQ5j8JtKnObLk">
      <wsse:KeyIdentifier
                        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
                        ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">h5...ow=</wsse:KeyIdentifier>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
  </dsig:KeyInfo>
</dsig:Signature>
```

Can someone explain me how to do the signature for such token? The step-by-step description of the algorithm, or an example using any language/library will be good.

[In this document is the description of the transformation](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16790/wss-v1.1-spec-os-SOAPMessageSecurity.pdf), from page 38, but I am unable to understand how to apply it in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after checking Oracle's WebLogic server debug and verbose log file having a working service example and setting the flags `-Dweblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.debug=true -Dweblogic.xml.crypto.dsig.verbose=true -Dweblogic.xml.crypto.keyinfo.debug=true -Dweblogic.xml.crypto.keyinfo.verbose=true -Dweblogic.wsee.verbose=* -Dweblogic.wsee.debug=*` (more info [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/vijaya/weblogic-server-debug-flags-:-deployment,-jta,-http,-jms-message-bridge,-cluster,-classloader,-webservice), [here](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/18/weblogic-server-debug-flags/), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/server_start/overview.html#1070190) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/logging.html#1048117)), thank God there was a preety good insight on how the security token was de-referenced. Basically, having a `SecurityTokenReference` for an x509 certificate, with a `KeyIdentifier`, is dereferenced as a `BinarySecurityToken` in this way:

```
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns="" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">CertificateBase64String</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Some important things to notice are:

- The ValueType, and thus the content of the `BinarySecurityToken`, is defined by the `TokenType` of the `SecurityTokenReference`. In this case, the text of the `BinarySecurityToken` is the x509 certificate that is referenced by the `KeyIdentifier` element, encoded as a base64 string.
- According to the specification, the `BinarySecurityToken` only includes the `ValueType` attribute. So it should not include the `EncodingType` attribute, neither the `Id` attribute that the `SecurityTokenReference` has.
- The same namespace prefix of the `SecurityTokenReference` is used. Also, the namespace for this prefix is included in the tag.
- The default namespace attribute is set as empty: `xmlns=""`

So basically the whole `SecurityTokenReference` element is replaced by the new `BinarySecurityToken`, and this is the one to be canonicalized and hashed (to get its digest value). Beware that it is canonicalized and digested as is, so the operation may provide a wrong result if the XML is simplified by removing the empty `xmlns` namespace or the prefix namespace, or by changing the namespace prefix.

The example `BinarySecurityToken` is already canonicalized using the algorithm "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#", so in .NET, to get the DigestValue using the digest algorithm "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256", is enough to do this:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create();
byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns=\"\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\" ValueType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3\">MIIF...2A8=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>"));
string digestValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

Comment: `it is canonicalized and digested as is, so the operation may provide a wrong result if the XML is simplified by removing the empty xmlns namespace or the prefix namespace, or by changing the namespace prefix.`  what do you mean by "empty xmlns namespace" ?  Can you elaborate? Are you saying that the referent , the BinarySecurityToken element, MUST explicitly include a toplevel attribute like `xmlns=""` ?

Comment: You also said "According to the specification, the BinarySecurityToken only includes the ValueType attribute." Can you cite the specification you're referring to?

Comment: @Cheeso about `it is canonicalized and digested as is` I mean that the dereferenced BinarySecurityToken should be taken exactly as it is, without removing any empty attributes. There are some parsing XML libraries that remove the `xmlns` attribute if it is empty.

Comment: @Cheeso about `According to the specification, the BinarySecurityToken only includes the ValueType attribute.`, to be honest, I don't remember. I think I meant the `Security` section in the message.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!